# Refresh StatefulBuilder Dialog without using onPressed

Tags: flutter, dialog, stateful

I need to update the text of my dialog while my report is loading. setState doest not work here.

```
class ReportW extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReportW({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ReportWState createState() => _ReportWState();
}

class _ReportWState extends State<ReportMenuDownloadW> {

  String loadingText;

  void updateLoadingText(text){
    setState(() {loadingText = text;});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MyWidget(
      label:REPORT_LABEL,
      onTap: () async {
        showDialog(context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (context, setState) {
                    return Dialog(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          Text(loadingText),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );});
            });
        await loadPDF(context,updateLoadingText);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Is there an alternative solution if it is not possible ? I just need a progress text indicator over my screen while loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use GlobalKey. For your code:

1. Define globalKey inside your widget:

```
// Global key for dialog
final GlobalKey _dialogKey = GlobalKey();
```

2. Set globalKey for your StatefulBuilder:

```
return StatefulBuilder(
  key: _dialogKey,
  builder: (context, setState) {
    return Dialog(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Text(loadingText),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

3. Now you can update UI of your dialog like this:

```
void updateLoadingText(text) {
  // Check if dialog displayed, we can't call setState when dialog not displayed
  if (_dialogKey.currentState != null && _dialogKey.currentState!.mounted) {
    _dialogKey.currentState!.setState(() {
      loadingText = text;
    });
  }
}
```

**Pay attention, you get unexpected behavior if user will close dialog manually.**

How to prevent closing dialog by user: in showDialog use `barrierDismissible: false` and also wrap your dialog to `WillPopScope` with `onWillPop: () async {return false;}`

Possible question:
Why we check `_dialogKey.currentState != null`?
Because opening dialog and set globalKey take some time and while it's not opened currentState is null. If `updateLoadingText` will be call before dialog will be open, we shouldn't update UI for dialog.

Full code of your widget:

```
class OriginalHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  OriginalHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OriginalHomePageState createState() => _OriginalHomePageState();
}

class _OriginalHomePageState extends State<OriginalHomePage> {
  String loadingText = "Start";

  // Global key for dialog
  final GlobalKey _dialogKey = GlobalKey();

  void updateLoadingText(text) {
    // Check if dialog displayed, we can't call setState when dialog not displayed
    if (_dialogKey.currentState != null && _dialogKey.currentState!.mounted) {
      _dialogKey.currentState!.setState(() {
        loadingText = text;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return StatefulBuilder(
              key: _dialogKey,
              builder: (context, setState) {
                return Dialog(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      Text(loadingText),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
        await loadPDF(context, updateLoadingText);
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text("Open"),
    );
  }
}
```

Also i rewrote your code a bit, it seems to me more correct:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Open"),
          onPressed: () => _showDialog(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Global key for dialog
  final GlobalKey _dialogKey = GlobalKey();

  // Text for update in dialog
  String _loadingText = "Start";

  _showDialog() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
            return false;
          },
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            key: _dialogKey,
            builder: (context, setState) {
              return Dialog(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      Text(_loadingText),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    // Call some function from service
    await myLoadPDF(context, _setStateDialog);

    // Close dialog
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  // Update dialog
  _setStateDialog(String newText) {
    // Check if dialog displayed, we can't call setState when dialog not displayed
    if (_dialogKey.currentState != null && _dialogKey.currentState!.mounted) {
      _dialogKey.currentState!.setState(() {
        _loadingText = newText;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

[Updated dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31xfA.gif)

Comment: Why is it more correct to write the code this way ?

Comment: For you case i added `barrierDismissible ` and `onWillPop` for dialog.
Generally:
1) Used strong type.
2) Private values should start from "_".
3) Used null-safety, https://dart.dev/null-safety.
4) Moved `showDialog` to separated function, now build function looks cleaner.
Your code still work without it, but you can used it to improve readability of your code and prevent potential bugs.